# Laravel Database Seeder only seeds some of first seeders

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've generated seeders using [ISEED](https://github.com/orangehill/iseed) package.
I also added the seeder classes to `DatabaseSeeder` class to run.

But laravel seeder only seeds first seeders of the list.

```php
use App\Setting;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (config('iseed.enable')) {
            $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(BrandsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(AttributesgroupTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(AttributesvalueTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(AddressesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ShipmentsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ProductsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CombinationsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(AttributegroupCategoryTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(AttributevalueProductTableSeeder::class);
//only seeds top seeders
            $this->call(AttributevalueCombinationTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(WpPostsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ActivityLogTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(AnnouncementsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ApiSessionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ArticleArticleCategoryTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ArticleCategoriesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CacheTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CitiesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CombinationOrderTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CommentLikesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CommentReportsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CommentsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CouponUserTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(CouponsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(FailedJobsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(FavoritesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(FeaturesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(FilterItemTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(FiltersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(InformationUsersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(JobsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(LinksTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MakeupArtistServicesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MakeupArtistsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MakeupArtistsInfoTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MarketersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MediasTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MessagesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MetaTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(MigrationsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ModelHasPermissionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ModelHasRolesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(NotificationsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(OrdersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(PasswordResetsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(PaymentsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(PopupsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ProductFeaturesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ProductImagesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ProductScoresTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ProvincesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(RateCategoriesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(RatesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(RoleHasPermissionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ServiceCategoriesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ServiceLabelsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ServicesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(SettingsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(SlidersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(SmsirlaravelLogsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(StatisticsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(StatisticsUsersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(TokensTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(TransactionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(TwoFactorsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(WalletChargePaymentsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(WalletPaymentsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(WalletsTableSeeder::class);
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment first lines It starts to seed few more again!

Comment: Check  if the seeder AttributevalueCombinationTableSeeder fails.  When a seeder fails to complete, it may leave the database in an inconsistent state which can cause subsequent seeders to fail or not run at all. Comment out all seeder except of the AttributevalueCombinationTableSeeder. Or run php artisan `db:seed --class=ClassNameSeeder`. Also try using `dd()` to identify the issue

Comment: Thank you @noah1400 . You guessed right. I added a foreach and try catch to continue and log the errors if a seeder fails. and it worked .. It would be good if you post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there may be an issue with the `AttributevalueCombinationTableSeeder` seeder class, which is causing subsequent seeders to fail or not run at all.

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try running the seeder class on its own using the `php artisan db:seed --class=AttributevalueCombinationTableSeeder` command. If the seeder runs successfully without any errors, then you can try adding back the other seeder classes one at a time to see if any of them are causing the issue.

If you are still unable to identify the issue, you can try using `dd()` statements in your seeders to debug the problem. For example, you can add `dd('Seeder class XYZ started');` at the beginning of each seeder class to verify that it is being called properly. You can also add `dd($data);` statements to check the data being passed to the seeder, and `dd($model->toArray());` statements to check the data being saved to the database.

Once you have identified the issue, you can fix the seeder class or make any necessary adjustments to your code to ensure that all seeders run successfully.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT output, which is banned on Stack Overflow.